# Runtime error 3704

Tags: vb6, adodb

In my vb6 I am getting error 3704 operation is not allowed when object is closed.

I have search stackoverflow for similar problem but I think I'm missing something. I need to update every row in vfp based from recordset rs1 Here my code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cn1 As New ADODB.Connection

Private Sub trns_Click()
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set cn1 = New ADODB.Connection

cn.ConnectionString = MDI1.txtcn.Text
cn.Open


cn1.ConnectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=\\host1\software\MIL\company0"
cn1.Open

rs1.Open "Select * from trans", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic



Do While Not rs2.EOF
    rs2.Open "update transac set no_ot_1_5 = " & rs1.Fields("ovt1") & ", no_ot_2_0 = " & rs1.Fields("ovt2") & ", no_ot_3_0" _
             & "= " & rs1.Fields("ovt3") & ",Meal_allw = " & rs1.Fields("meal_allow") & ",on_duty = " & rs1.Fields("cnt") & ",no_d_local = " & rs1.Fields("local") & ",no_d_sick" _
             & "= " & rs1.Fields("sick") & ",no_d_abs = " & rs1.Fields("absence") & ",no_d_spc = " & rs1.Fields("special") & ",Revenue02" _
             & "= " & rs1.Fields("refund") & ",Revenue05 = " & rs1.Fields("prepay") & ",Deduct05 = " & rs1.Fields("prepay") & ",Revenue01 = " & rs1.Fields("comm") & "where code = '" & rs1.Fields("emp_code") & "' and transac.date = CTOD('" & trans.txtend2 & "')", cn1, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic

    If Not rs2.EOF Then
      rs2.MoveNext
    End If
Loop
rs2.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Update query doesn't return recordset, hence your rs2 is not opened.

Comment: thank you for your response Arvo.But when i do not put the do while code.Only one record is updated.I need to update every row in rs2 from rs1.Can you advise me please

Comment: Why you're using recordset open function for updates? Why you're looping on rs2? How many records are in rs1, which one is in your interests? Why you can't use set based operations for updating? Methinks that your program logic is not very clear either.

Comment: The VFP Provider has some funky limitations. SELECT INTO and INSERT INTO probably don't work, even assuming you could use a linked table, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You perform your loop on the wrong recordeset : I replaced the some of the rs2 with rs1 in your code.

```
Do While Not rs1.EOF
    rs2.Open "update transac set no_ot_1_5 = " & rs1.Fields("ovt1") & ", no_ot_2_0 = " & rs1.Fields("ovt2") & ", no_ot_3_0" _
             & "= " & rs1.Fields("ovt3") & ",Meal_allw = " & rs1.Fields("meal_allow") & ",on_duty = " & rs1.Fields("cnt") & ",no_d_local = " & rs1.Fields("local") & ",no_d_sick" _
             & "= " & rs1.Fields("sick") & ",no_d_abs = " & rs1.Fields("absence") & ",no_d_spc = " & rs1.Fields("special") & ",Revenue02" _
             & "= " & rs1.Fields("refund") & ",Revenue05 = " & rs1.Fields("prepay") & ",Deduct05 = " & rs1.Fields("prepay") & ",Revenue01 = " & rs1.Fields("comm") & "where code = '" & rs1.Fields("emp_code") & "' and transac.date = CTOD('" & trans.txtend2 & "')", cn1, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic

    If Not rs1.EOF Then
      rs1.MoveNext
    End If
Loop
rs1.close
```

Comment: Might be better to get rid of rs2 and use cn1.Execute instead, this isn't what a Recordset is for.  Get rid of "Do While Not EOF" double-negative and use "Do Until EOF" instead.  Don't check for EOF a second time inside the loop, it's pointless.  Are you sure you want UPDATE and not INSERT here?

Comment: @Bob Riemersma I agree with you, and there is still one hundred thing wrong with this code that could (or should) be improved. I try to help the user by doing the minimum modification to his code. Meanwhile, I strongly encourage you to write you own answer.

Comment: Arvo,@Bob Riemersma .Thank you very much for your help.Yes I need to update a vfp table.I have created a linked server in sql but i couldnt update it.So i call the rs1 from sql and then update the vfp in vb6.I would apreciate if you can guide me on the best solution to implement.Thank again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create a recordset to execute an update, insert or delete on the database. Just use the statement cn1.Execute YourSqlStatement where YourSqlStatement is the string you are passing on the rs2.Open instruction. The Execute method on the connection optionally accepts a byRef variable where you can get the number of records affected.

Example:

```
Dim nRecords As Integer    
cn1.Execute "Update Table Set Field = Value Where AnotherField = SomeValue ", nRecords
MsgBox "Total Updated Records: " & Format(nRecords,"0")
```

Answer (score 0):

try to open your rs2 before using if in the do while statement.,  or do it like this

```
rs2.open " blah blah blah "

Do Until rs2.eof
    For Each fld In rs2.field 
        value_holder = fld.value
    Next

    rs2.movenext
Loop
```